# Why drupal_get_form will reset variables?

Tags: forms

I would like to implement a simple searching form.

When the form is posted, the searching result will be shown before the form.

The page callback is as following.

`$output` have content at the first line, but no content at the second line.

Why `drupal_get_form` have this side effect?

Or do I have a bad idea about this implementation.

```
function _camp_search_page() {
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {node} n JOIN {field_data_field_camp_order} o ON n.nid = o.entity_id WHERE n.type = 'camp_reg' AND n.title = :name";
        $result = db_query($sql, array(":name" => $_POST['name']))->fetchAll();
        if($result){
            $output .= "<ul class='camp-order-list'>";
            foreach($result as $order){
                $output .= "<li class='camp-order'><a href='/camp/pay/$order->field_camp_order_value/$order->nid'>Click</a></li>";
            }

            $output .= "</ul>";
        }
    }
    dpm($output); // There is $output here
    $search_form = drupal_get_form('camp_search_form');
    dpm($output); // $output become empty here.
    $search_form['#prefix'] = $output;
    return $search_form;
}
```

### update

Drupal will redirect the browser to a new page when the submitted form is processed. Although I don't where and how this is happening, the two lines of `dpm` seem to executed in different request.

Comment: so is the whole processing stopping or is it getting to the return statement at the end?

Comment: @rooby The code is running well except the `$output` became empty. The form is rendered without any prefix.

Comment: do you have any errors in the logs?

Comment: @rooby There is no error. Seems like drupal redirected to a new page after the form is submitted, and the two dpm are not executed at the same         request?